# Directly Capturing Multible USB Barcodes in Delphi

Tags: delphi, barcode

I just finished coding a USB relay board to open and close 2 relays. First time doing any kind of .DLL programming. But now I need to code two USB bar code scanners on the same PC.

1. First I need to know which one of the scanners is being scanned.(I'm calling it -scan in/scan out)
2. And Secondly I need to capture the string to check against a database, but doing this without the scanner influencing any other program running, like if I'm focused on notepad while scanning, no text should appear on notepad.

Any info will be appreciated and Some Sample code even more.

Comment: I did not find an english link: http://gruppen.niuz.biz/wie-t60980.html. You could use JWAWinUser from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jedi-apilib/files/ and work with GetRawInputData and GetRawInputDeviceInfo.

Comment: Is there any example code for (a drop down to show all the UBS's) then selecting one USB and redirect the traffic to a edit box? I've been coding for some time in Delphi but mostly database driven stuff, so its quite difficult for me figuring out the finer details.

Comment: SO would expect you to show some effort and asking a question showing some code you already have written, with description of what is not working as expected. Questions    asking for some code or library are off topic.

Comment: How do you read the codes from single scanner?

Answer (score 0):

Most barcode scanners behave like keyboards: you can use several at once, but finding out which one is doing what is not easy. I think the easiest way to do what you want is to use 2 cheap computers such as a Raspberry PI, plug a scanner on each ones and send codes to your application though IP. Considering the price of a barcode scanner, the price of 2 PI shouldn't be that much.

Comment: For now i'll go with the 2 pc route thanks, one I have more time I'll try something like JWAWinUser

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can program the barcode scanner with a prefix and a suffix code. For example a barcode like 123456789 get a prefix likes #S and a suffix likes #E when you scan a barcode, the barcodescanner sends #S123456789#E so you know the start and the end of the barcode. For the Second barcode you program de prefix en suffix with an other code for example #Q and #W so the second barcode scanner sends #Q123456789#W